# PHP preg_split by new line with \R

Tags: php, regex, pcre

As far as I understand the following line of code should split a string at new lines (`\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`).

```
preg_split("%\R%", $str);
```

Why is it that

```
var_dump(preg_split("%\R%", "Å"));
```

outputs

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "▒"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

but

```
var_dump(preg_split("%(\r|\n|\r\n)%", "Å"));
```

works as expected and does not split the character? I know that I should use the "u" modifier (PCRE_UTF8) because the character is in UTF-8 but why does `preg_split` think that Å (`0xC3 0x85`) could contain a new line?

Comment: As @anubhava's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44800979/4265352) explains, despite what is mentioned in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), the `\x85` character is recognized as a [newline sequence](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#newlineseq) by the PCRE library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have also mentioned that `Å` is `0xC3 0x85`

As per [this PCRE documentation](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#newlineseq) without using `u` modifier `\R` is equivalent of this atomic group:

```
(?>\r\n|\n|\r|\f|\x0b|\x85)
```

Note presence of `\x85` in both sets.

Hence split on `\R` without using `u` modifier gives one extra element in output array since it is able to split on `\x85` giving you just `\xC3` and an empty result in resulting array.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the definition of `\R`? The [Escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) page of the PHP documentation about PCRE says just: *"matches `\n`, `\r` and `\r\n`"*.

Comment: PHP documentation is incomplete actually. [Check this official PCRE doc](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) and section under **Newline sequences** heading.

Comment: Found a linkable version of the reference: http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#newlineseq. It's good to know.

Comment: Thanks, that is much better. I am adding this link to answer as well.